Virtual WDS AP Can't Connect to Home WiFi Network
I'm running Ubuntu Server 23.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4B. I have WDS/4addr enabled on my USB-WiFi Dongle (that has AP capabilities), and have created a virtual network named 'wds0' that would connect to my home network. When running the command
sudo nmcli device wifi connect "My Network" password "Password" ifname wds0
I get the following error:
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
I'll add this command works just fine when using the original device and not the virtual one, so I'm guessing it has to do with setting up an extra IP Addressing step? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
